# TexStudio, How to search multiple strings in one search

Tags: texstudio

In TexStudio, we can search and highlight one string, e.g. "stringA".

However, how to search and highlight "stringA" and "stringB" in just one search? which should highlight both "stringA" and "stringB", and then may be replaced by "stringC".

Before replacement:

```
stringA is stringB
```

After:

```
stringC is stringC
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable regular expression in the `search and replace` menu.

So searching for `string[AB]` should give the desired result.

[image]